# I want to get the status of running apps

Tags: android

Examples of app status: foreground / background!

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search provided me [this article](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=26841). The basics are:

In your manifest file add the permission:

```
<uses-permission id="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

In your Activity do something like this:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 private void updateTaskList() {
      /* Grab the Systems IActivityManager. */
      IActivityManager myActivityManager = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault();
      /* Will hold all the task"".toString()"" entries */
      ArrayList<String> listEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
      try {
           int showLimit = 1;
           /* Get all Tasks available (with limit set). */
           List<IActivityManager.TaskInfo> allTasks = myActivityManager
                     .getTasks(showLimit, 0, null);
           int i = 1;
           /* Loop through all tasks returned. */
           for (IActivityManager.TaskInfo aTask : allTasks) {
                listEntries
                          .add("" + (i++) + ": "
                                    + aTask.baseActivity.getClassName() + " ID="
                                    + aTask.id);
           }
      } catch (DeadObjectException e) {
           Log.e("TaskManager", e.getMessage(), e);
      }
      /* Display out listEntries */
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1_small, listEntries));
 }
```

Please note that I haven't tried this... it's just from that site I linked above.

Comment: I don't see IActivityManager listed in the docs, so I think this is old code.

Comment: I posted this 9mos ago... things change.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    ConfigurationInfo config = mgr.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = mgr.getRunningAppProcesses();
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = mgr.getRunningTasks(100);

    String text = "";

    text += "Running tasks: \n";
    for(Iterator i = tasks.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
    {
        RunningTaskInfo p = (RunningTaskInfo)i.next();
        text += p.baseActivity.flattenToString() + "\n";
    }
```

EtCeTeRa

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't — there is no API for this.

Slightly more accurate answer: you *may* be able to run a command like `ps` to get some basic process information, but this depends on whether the specific device lets you execute console commands like that, and has the `ps` binary installed.

Comment: Then how do all those Task Manager apps exist?

Comment: I imagine they use non-public APIs, as in your answer.